# NWJS window loaded is not available

Tags: nwjs, nwjs-contexts

The [NWJS documentation](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Window/#synopsis) states that after opening a window, you have to wait for the `loaded` event before you can interact with it:

> You should wait for the Window’s `loaded` event before interacting with any of its components.

So I tried to add a `loaded` event handler for the win object after opening it.

```
nw.Window.open('test.html', {}, (win) => { 
    win.showDevTools()
    win.addEventListener("loaded", () => {
        console.log("NW Window loaded not working...")
    })
}
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: win.addEventListener is not a function

How can I listen for NWWindow events in NWJS? Sidenote: I *CAN* listen for DOM window load events, but that's not the same is it?

```
nw.Window.open('test.html', options, (win) => { 
    win.showDevTools()
    win.window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        console.log("dom window load IS working...")
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example on how to use the Event Listener on the nw.Window:

```js
nw.Window.open('test.html', {}, win => { 
    win.showDevTools();
    win.on("loaded", () => {
        console.log("NW Window loaded not working...")
    })
}
```

Example from [here](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Window/#event-new-win-policy-frame-url-policy), I changed it so that it fits to your problem

- Edit: I changed the nw.Window.get() to win

Answer (score 1):

`addEventListener` is from DOM. Refer https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_addlistener_eventname_listener & then try again. Also `console` may work as `win.window.console` here.

Comment: Ah, I never noticed it says `addListener` instead of `addEventListener`....